# View: Display all folder having at least one child which property has selected value

Tags: 2013, list, view, folder

I have folders, each folder have children (document sets, but that doesn't really matter).

How, if possible, can I create a new view that will list all the folders for which at least one child has the property PROP_A having the value ABC?

[image: Schema of the desired result]

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you using?

Comment: @aliJafer 2013, I edited the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OOTB you can create a custom view. Set the filter to look against if its content type column is a folder or Prop_A = ABC. this will filter the underlying item but will show all folders.

unfortunately to get the folders only showing that actually contain any items within them would require a coded method.